# How to set RETAIN publish message for flutter Mqtt_client

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt, android-mqtt-client

Now I can publish message using this

```
MqttServerClient client = MqttServerClient.withPort(broker, "", 1883); //connect broker

//create message
final builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
builder.addString(message);

client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload); //publish message
```

but how can I set published message to Retain.

Comment: I believe that `client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload, true);` is what you are looking for ([docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/mqtt_client/latest/mqtt_client/MqttClient/publishMessage.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/mqtt_client/latest/mqtt_client/MqttClient/publishMessage.html) the syntax is:

```dart
int publishMessage(

    String topic,
    MqttQos qualityOfService,
    Uint8Buffer data,
    {bool retain = false}

)
```

So your `publish` would need to be:

```dart
client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload, retain:true);
```

Comment: It is a named argument:

client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload, retain:true);